# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is giving me troubles when Logging Out and back in to a MERN app. I've read some things about a componentWillUnmount and use State etc, but its all very confusing.. Here is the issue..

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
in Dashboard (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (at PrivateRoute.js:11)

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
    auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
      <Component {...props} /> // THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE ERROR (at PrivateRoute.js:11)
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

The error also expands with the following:

```
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)     
push../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js.Request.create   @   polling-xhr.js:268
Request @   polling-xhr.js:170
push../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js.XHR.request  @   polling-xhr.js:96
push../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling-xhr.js.XHR.doPoll   @   polling-xhr.js:126
push../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling.js.Polling.poll @   polling.js:118
push../node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/polling.js.Polling.onData   @   polling.js:157
```

**Am I not closing a XHR request properly?**

**EDIT**
It seems I found a request is not being completed:
Request URL: ws://localhost:3000/sockjs-node
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols

Request call stack

- ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js @
  webpackHotDevClient.js
- **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:784
- fn @ bootstrap:150
- 1 @ setAuthToken.js:14
- **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:784
- checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
- webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
- (anonymous) @
  main.chunk.js:1

**Just throwing this out there, is the browser looking for the 'React Developer Tools' to connect to??**

Comment: It looks like there may be a HTTP call no finishing before a component is unmounted. Hard to say for sure without seeing the remaining code. I recommend looking at which component is rendered when you get this issue and debug there.

Comment: @MMansour OK, going to try to wait before logging out and back in to see if there was any HTTP calls not being finished..

Comment: @MMansour Hmm, I notice when stopping the server, I get non-stop GET HTTP calls within (polling-xhr.js) @ xhr.send(this.data);